# Why Intel 4004 published schematics uses NMOS, if the 4004 was produced only with PMOS?

Tags: schematics, vintage, intel

According to Wikipedia[0]:

> The 4004 employs an 10 μm process silicon-gate enhancement-load pMOS technology on a 12 mm2 die[36]

In 2006 Intel released original schematics of 4004 CPU [1]. Seemingly it uses NMOS transistors only.

The analysis that I found (e.g. [2]) confirms that the transistors in schematics are NMOS indeed.

What is the explanation of that inconsistency?

[0] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_4004

[1] https://slashdot.org/story/06/11/14/2356255/intel-releases-4004-microprocessor-schematics

[2] http://insanity4004.blogspot.com/2020/07/another-bug-in-original-i4004.html

EDIT: The schematics that I mean is for example this one:

http://datasheets.chipdb.org/Intel/MCS-4/4004_schematic.pdf

Comment: I've a question for you to consider. Wikipedia isn't perfect and mistakes are sometimes made. It certainly does write pMOS. But the original paper by Faggin & Klein, then while still at Fairchild (Hoff at Intel hired Faggin in 1970), on the silicon gate technology that Intel used for the 4004 describes both n- and p- MOS. I'm not disagreeing with the Wikipedia statement. It very well may have been the pMOS version used by Intel. But what have you done to verify that Wikipedia's statement is accurate? (They don't provide a reference that I can see.) The inconsistency might be a simple typo.

Comment: (The paper I'm referencing is Faggin, F., & Klein, T. (1970). "Silicon gate technology", *Solid-State Electronics*, 13(8), 1125–1144. doi:10.1016/0038-1101(70)90124-3.)

Comment: Original Intel specs says in the Title "p-channel microprocessor". https://web.archive.org/web/20131101060923/http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/DataSheet/4004_datasheet.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the link. :) I think you should include that in your question, not in comments. Sometimes, comments gets dumped into some chat log where people won't see them and the link directly addresses any question like mine.

Comment: [This article on pMOS and the 4004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PMOS_logic) provokes a thought or two. They discuss why pMOS would have been chosen, initially. But they also point out that by 1972, those issues were on track to being resolved. This is right at the cusp of the 4004 release timing. So it makes me wonder if Intel attempted both pMOS (earlier) and nMOS (later.) I've no reason to think so. But the article makes me wonder if that may have occurred, even if they never released the nMOS version in packaged form. Why not contact Intel, directly, and ask?

Comment: Did you try reading this article? http://uvicrec.blogspot.com/2011/09/understanding-intel-4004.html?m=1

Comment: What exactly is the evidence for NMOS? Keep in mind that the schematic symbol conventions we're so familiar with today were not commonly used back in those days. Note also the power supply polarity: on the 4004 (and 8008), Vdd = -9V and Vss = +5V. These chips were definitely PMOS.

Comment: More reference resources here: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/20311/4183